# Error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 14 - Netbeans 12

Tags: java, netbeans

When compiling I figure the following problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the file, the version of the JDK must be changed, since it was in version 14 and it was changed to version 1.8JDK:

[image]